# How to create function (number, from, to) with a returning interval of boolean + input&print out

Tags: javascript, html, function, return, boolean

I've tried searching here on Stackoverflow and on Google search engine on creating a function(number, from, to) in a interval, that returns with boolean and get their data from an input source with having the possiblity of a print out on the page. I've tried different types of combinations, but the text will not appear on the page at all. By the way, if possible I'd like to accomplish this without using php and jquery. My task is to check if a number is within the from and to interval.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- JS -->
        window.onload = oppstart;

        function oppstart(tall, fra, til){
          document.getElementById("btnVisSvaret").onclick=innenforInterval;
          document.getElementById("storre").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("mindre").innerHTML = "";

          if (innenforInterval(parseInt(tall, parseInt(fra), parseInt(til) === true)))
          {
            document.getElementById("utskrift1").innerHTML = ("Ja! Tallet er innenfor intervallet!");
          }
          else {
            document.getElementById("utskrift2").innerHTML = ("Nei! Tallet er ikke innenfor intervallet!");
          }
        }

        function InnenforInterval(tall, fra, til){
          if(tall < til  || tall > fra){
          return false;
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
      }
      </script>

    <p> Sjekk om et spesifikt tall er innenfor intervallet </p>

      Er tallet: <input id="siffere"/></input>
      <br></br>

      Større enn: <input id="storre"/></input>
      og mindre enn: <input id="mindre"/></input>

      <button id="btnVisSvaret" type="button"
      value="getElementById("storre")",
      value="getElementById("mindre")",
      value="getElementById("siffere")";/> Vis Svaret </button>

      <p id="utskrift1"/></p>
      <p id="utskrift2"/></p>
```

Comment: The markup is invalid

Comment: @Andreas Are you reffering to the way I wrote my codes on a coding program or here on SO? Because in my screen, it looks like how it should be. If I compare it to other posts that do include codes in their post.

Comment: The HTML shown in your question is invalid

Comment: I tried fixing it, but to be quite honest. I can seem to see where the issue in the text is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand it correctly, you want to check a number if it is inside of the given interval.

I have stripped the code a bit and now ther are only two function which makes the code working.

Please have a look to the button, ther is no value attribute. This is an attribute of input tag.

```js
window.onload = oppstart;

function oppstart() {
    document.getElementById("btnVisSvaret").onclick = innenforInterval;
}

function innenforInterval() {
    var tall = +document.getElementById('siffere').value,
        fra = +document.getElementById('mindre').value,
        til = +document.getElementById('storre').value;

    console.log(tall, fra, til);
    if (tall >= fra && tall <= til) {
        document.getElementById("utskrift1").innerHTML = "Ja! Tallet er innenfor intervallet!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("utskrift2").innerHTML = "Nei! Tallet er ikke innenfor intervallet!";
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Sjekk om et spesifikt tall er innenfor intervallet</p>
Er tallet:<input id="siffere" /><br>
Større enn: <input id="storre" />
og mindre enn:<input id="mindre" />
<button id="btnVisSvaret" />Vis Svaret</button>
<p id="utskrift1" /></p>
<p id="utskrift2" /></p>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch for bothering and taking time of your day to actually answer my question. It is much appreciated. I think I understand what the meaning of the changes you actually did. But I have ask if this is possible. The first input area is meant for the user to write a number like say for an example 5. Then the second input area says bigger then: which if you select the number 6 and the third input area says smaller then: which if you select number 3. You should get this message: Yes the number you selected is within the interval.